# El sistema usado en la página es lento, ¿alguna forma de optimizarlo?

Tags: php, json, mysqli, optimización

Tengo este sistema de comentarios pero tarda mucho en cargar. ¿Hay alguna solución?

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel-body">

<!--Inicio elementos contenedor-->

<div class="comment-form-container">
            <form id="frm-comment">
                <div class="input-row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comentario_id" id="commentId"
                           placeholder="Name" /> <input class="input-field"
                           type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombres" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-row">
                    <textarea class="input-field" type="text" name="comment"
                              id="comment" placeholder="Agregar comentario">  </textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn-submit" id="submitButton"
                           value="Publicar Ahora" /><div id="comment-message">Comentario ha sido agregado exitosamente!</div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>

        <script>
            var totalLikes = 0;
            var totalUnlikes = 0;

            function postReply(commentId) {
                $('#commentId').val(commentId);
                $("#name").focus();
            }

            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
                var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "AgregarComentario.php",
                    data: str,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                        if (response)
                        {
                            $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#name").val("");
                            $("#comment").val("");
                            $("#commentId").val("");
                            listComment();
                        } else
                        {
                            alert("Failed to add comments !");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                listComment();
            });

            function listComment() {
                $.post("ListaDeComentarios.php",
                        function (data) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            var comments = "";
                            var replies = "";
                            var item = "";
                            var parent = -1;
                            var results = new Array();

                            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
                            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

                            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                            {
                                var commentId = data[i]['comentario_id'];
                                parent = data[i]['parent_comentario_id'];

                                var obj = getLikesUnlikes(commentId);

                                if (parent == "0")
                                {
                                    if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                                    {
                                        like_icon = "<img src='img/MeGusta.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='img/NoMeGusta.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",1)' />";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                           like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='img/MeGusta.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img src='img/NoMeGusta.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",1)' />";

                                    }

                                    comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>De</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>a las </span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'>Responder</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'>\ " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + commentId + "'> " + totalLikes + " Me Gusta </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                                    list.append(item);
                                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                                    item.append(reply_list);
                                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
                                }
                            }
                            $("#output").html(list);
                        });
            }

            function listReplies(commentId, data, list) {

                for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                {

                    var obj = getLikesUnlikes(data[i].comentario_id);
                    if (commentId == data[i].parent_comentario_id)
                    {
                        if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                        {
                            like_icon = "<img src='img/MeGusta.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                            like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='img/NoMeGusta.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                         like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='img/NoMeGusta.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                         like_icon += "<img src='img/NoMeGusta.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        var comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>De </span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>a las </span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + ")'>Responder</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'> " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + data[i]['comentario_id'] + "'> " + totalLikes + " Me Gusta </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                        var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                        var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                        list.append(item);
                        item.append(reply_list);
                        listReplies(data[i].comentario_id, data, reply_list);
                    }
                }
            }

            function getLikesUnlikes(commentId)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: 'Envio_MeGusta.php',
                    data: {comentario_id: commentId},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        totalLikes = data;
                    }

                });

            }


           function likeOrDislike(comentario_id,like_unlike)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'MeGusta_NoMeGusta.php',
                    async: false,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {comentario_id:comentario_id,like_unlike:like_unlike},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("#likes_"+comentario_id).text(data + " likes");

                        if (like_unlike == 1) { 
                            $("#like_" + comentario_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#unlike_" + comentario_id).show();
                        }

                        if (like_unlike == -1) {
                            $("#unlike_" + comentario_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#like_" + comentario_id).show();
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error : " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            }



        </script>
```

**Agregarcomentario.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("Conexion.php");
$commentId = isset($_POST['comentario_id']) ? $_POST['comentario_id'] : "";
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : "";
$commentSenderName = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO comentario(parent_comentario_id,comment,comment_sender_name,date) VALUES ('" . $commentId . "','" . $comment . "','" . $commentSenderName . "','" . $date . "')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (! $result) {
    $result = mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo $result;
?>
```

**Enviomegusta.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("Conexion.php");

$commentId = $_POST['comentario_id'];
$totalLikes = "No ";
$likeQuery = "SELECT sum(like_unlike) AS likesCount FROM megusta_nomegusta WHERE comentario_id=".$commentId;
$resultLikeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$likeQuery);
$fetchLikes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLikeQuery,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(isset($fetchLikes['likesCount'])) {
    $totalLikes = $fetchLikes['likesCount'];
}

echo $totalLikes;
?>
```

**Listadocomentarios.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("Conexion.php");
$memberId = 1;
$sql = "SELECT comentario.*,megusta_nomegusta.like_unlike FROM comentario LEFT JOIN megusta_nomegusta ON comentario.comentario_id = megusta_nomegusta.comentario_id AND member_id = " . $memberId . " ORDER BY parent_comentario_id asc, comentario_id asc";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$record_set = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($record_set, $row);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($record_set);
?>
```

**megusta-nomegusta.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("Conexion.php");

$memberId = 1;
$commentId = $_POST['comentario_id'];
$likeOrUnlike = 0;
if($_POST['like_unlike'] == 1)
{
$likeOrUnlike = $_POST['like_unlike'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM megusta_nomegusta WHERE comentario_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (! empty($row)) 
{
    $query = "UPDATE megusta_nomegusta SET like_unlike = " . $likeOrUnlike . " WHERE  comentario_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
} else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO megusta_nomegusta(member_id,comentario_id,like_unlike) VALUES ('" . $memberId . "','" . $commentId . "','" . $likeOrUnlike . "')";
}
mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$totalLikes = "No ";
$likeQuery = "SELECT sum(like_unlike) AS likesCount FROM megusta_nomegusta WHERE comentario_id=".$commentId;
$resultLikeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$likeQuery);
$fetchLikes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLikeQuery,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(isset($fetchLikes['likesCount'])) {
    $totalLikes = $fetchLikes['likesCount'];
}

echo $totalLikes;
?>
```

Comment: Hola! ¿podrías explicarlo un poco?

Comment: Alfredo tendrías que ir discriminando, ejecutando el código por parte, para poder determinar **cuál es la parte que está lenta**. Tienes por ejemplo varias llamadas a archivos PHP y para nosotros es totalmente imposible saber a qué se debe la lentitud. Una forma rápida de verificar si la lentitud es debida a esos archivos sería crear en cada caso un archivo sencillo que devuelva un solo dato y probar con esos archivos. Si funciona rápido ya tendrás más identificado el problema. Luego vas agregando uno a uno los archivos reales y vas probando, y así sucesivamente...

Comment: Hola trata de añadir tu PHP para ver que puede estar haciendo lenta la consulta asi como tu diseño de tablas, en los scripts no esta el error, la lentitud se debe a que el success del ajax siempre espera a por una respuesta del servidor, y si el servidor tarda en responder lo que hay en el success tarda en ejecutarse

Comment: El problema que tienes es que lanzas primero `listComment()` que en su interior obtiene el listado de mensajes por XHR asíncrono (bien) y al devolver el resultado lanzas una nueva consulta XHR síncrona (usando `async: false`) por cada uno `getLikesUnlikes()`, que encadena el tiempo de carga de cada consulta XHR una tras otra. Deberías darle una vuelta a tu código para que todo pueda ser asíncrono o, incluso, obtener los "me gusta" desde el listado de comentarios.

Comment: @ErnestoRM cuando hago comentarios y envio tarda en cargar mucho la pagina....voy a ver si lo puedo subir al servidor y lo puedo mostrar

Comment: @A.Cedano he intentado hacer lo que me comentas y me da error ...imagino que he hecho algo mal

Comment: @OscarGarcia que quieres decir con dar una vuelta? he revisado código y no se donde cambiarlo

Comment: jorge como lo publico? tengo 4 archivos php.

Comment: Alfredo, con "dar una vuelta" (perdón por la expresión típica española) me refería a rehacerlo sin depender de consultas síncronas (quitar el `async: false` que, por cierto, está obsoleto y eliminado en versiones de jQuery modernas). ¿Qué versión usas? Trataré de hacer una prueba de concepto mañana cuando encuentre un hueco.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia estos son los scrip y ccs: Es un modelo que encontre hecho....                             
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que cada vez que accedes al fichero `index.php`haces una llamada a la función `listComment()`que lista todos los comentarios, dentro de esta función y por cada comentario llamas a la función `listReplies()` que lista las réplicas de cada comentario.

Por cada elemento que has añadido a cada una se esta listas(por cada comentario con sus réplicas) haces una llamada ala función `getLikesUnlikes()`. Esta función, por cada elemento de cada lista hace una llamada al fichero `Envio_MeGusta.php`que se encarga de hacer una consulta a la base de datos para contar los "Me gusta" que tiene dicho comentario.

Es decir, haces esto:

```
for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
{
 var obj = getLikesUnlikes(data[i].comentario_id);
                     .
                     .
                     .
```

Donde `data` es la lista de comentarios.

Esto supone una conexión extra por cada comentario y por cada una de sus réplicas ya que el dato de cuántos "Me gusta" tiene es algo que consultas directamente en "ListaDeComantarios.php".

Para optimizar podrías directamente eliminar esta línea

```
var obj = getLikesUnlikes(data[i].comentario_id);
```

tanto en `listComment()`como en `listReplies()` puesto que no haces uso de las variables donde almacenas estos valores.

Comment: funciona!!!! Puedo valorar las dos respuestas? solo me deja 1 .                                                                                                         
 Ahora solo me falta paginar este sistema ¿Hago pregunta en otro foro?

Comment: Me alegro y encantado de ayudarte! Puedes votar a favor o en contra de cualquier pregunta pero sólo aceptar una. Si tienes más dudas, tienes que hacer otra pregunta en el foro. Un saludo y suerte!

Comment: Perfecto!! Voy a ello. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Sin meternos en el código, puedes optimizar la carga de recursos en el cliente:

- Cambiar la carga de bootstrap al CDN, seguramente cuando un usuario visite la página ya este en caché. Tienes los enlaces en la página oficial:
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ Lo mismo deberías hacer para jQuery.

En cuanto a tus estilos:

```
<link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

asegurate de que están minificados.

> Editado

Analizando el servidor de prueba que pusiste: http://servidorprueba.club/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se está haciendo una llamada al fichero "Envio_MeGusta.php" esperando por la respuesta 2 segundos, cuando llega vuelve a enviarse una petición y se espera 2 segundos, y así sucesivamente... Tienes un problema en la forma en que solicitas los datos, revisa eso.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta perdona mi ignorancia...¿Que significa cambiar carga al CDN?

Comment: Ahora estás cargando todos los recursos desde tu servidor, por lo que el navegador los trata como "recursos únicos". Al usar un CDN, los cargas desde otro servidor, que los tiene disponibles y  comparte con muchas más páginas web, por lo que al cargar tu página, por primera vez (o después de un tiempo) el navegador probablemente no tiene que volver a bajar los css / js, sino que ya los tenga en caché provenientes de otra página que hayamos visitado. Todas estas librerías son muy muy pesadas, si multitud de sitios web no las enlazan del mismo origen usarlas ralentiza mucho la carga.